# laravel8 : does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i want to show all of my categories in navbar and show their subcategories in dropdown
like this :

[image]

i have a `home.blade.php`  and extended the nav blade in it , and have a HomeController too.

The problem is that I can show the categories and subcategories but not the titles of subs.

when i  use foreach for nav , `{{$category->children}}` works and shows all of the children but when i use it {{`$category->children->title`}} it doesn't work and says :

`Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance`

In addition, the relationship between category and subcategory is as follows:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
         'parent_id','title' , 'description', 'status',
    ];

    public function parent()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }


    public function children(){
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class , 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

so this is my HomeController :

```
 public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::with('children')
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->get();

        return view('home.home' , compact('categories'));
    }
```

and my nav blade :

```
 @foreach($categories as $category)
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> {{ $category->title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
          <li><a href="#">{{ $category->children->title }}</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    @endforeach
```

And as I mentioned above, I just extended the nav in  Home blade

can you please tell me where where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do another foreach loop for the children to parse them out.

Change your nav blade to:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> {{ $category->title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
          @foreach($category->children as $child)
             <li><a href="#">{{ $child->title }}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: how can i query on children? for example i want to show just 5 subcategories and when i use `take(5)` in controller, it limits categories

Comment: `$categories = Category::with(['children' => function($q) { $q->take(5); }])->whereNull('parent_id')->get();`